# Is it possible to have one proguard mappings.txt file for multiple flavor?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I would like to publish my app to multiple market. the version code should be same in all market and my app has IAP so i should have multiple flavor and one manifest per flavor.
And also i need the mapping file for the crash report(for example in tracepot).

My problem is: How can i have one `mappings.txt` file for multiple flavor?

**build.gradle:**

```
android {
productFlavors {
    Market1 {
            ...
    }
    Market2 {
            ....
    }
signingConfigs {
    debug {
            ....
    }

    release {
            ....
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

    release {
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't your proguard rules in the buildtype section? Doesn't this then apply to all flavors already?

Comment: I think if you dont specify `proguardFiles` in your product flavor declaration, gradle will use the ones specified in your build types declaration (specifically the release type)

Comment: i attach my gradle file @eriuzo

Comment: I attached my gradle file @RaGe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the current settings in your `build.gradle` will apply the proguard file to all release builds of all flavors. You already have it there.

**Update after the conversation with OP in comments below:**

Now i understood the question better. You are trying to have a single `mapping.txt` file and are not talking about the `proguard-rules.pro`. The answer is **No, you cannot have a single file for multiple generated apks.** Proguard rules are applied to each flavor separately and each time it generates a separate mapping file. There might not be a any differences in your `mapping.txt` files right now because you may not be using different sourceSets (Java classes). But, if you have different `sourceSets`, the `mappings.txt` file will not be the same. Probably you have only minimal difference between your flavors right now like different drawables with same name, If i'm assuming right.

Comment: it make different mapping file for each flavor :(

Comment: how did you identify that? can you share the info so that we can take a look?

Comment: I compare both files and see they are same

Comment: so why it create 2 mapping file in different folder?

Comment: i mean 'mapping.txt' file

Comment: oh that. proguard is applied individually for each flavor and hence the separate mapping file. But the fact that you have two mapping files means that the proguard rules were applied to both flavors, which was your main concern.

Comment: Now i understand your question better. Check updated answer.